# App open a wkwebview, can,t scroll and wait 3s app crash

Tags: ios, iphone, webview, crash, wkwebview

The same code run to iphone se, or other one 5s is not crash

The crashed iphone is a iphone5s.

This crash is in **WKWebview**

This is the crash log：

```
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2017-02-21 19:28:26.069 +0800
Launch Time:         2017-02-21 19:27:45.145 +0800
OS Version:          iOS 8.4.1 (12H321)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  12

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1846a022c __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x19631c0e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1846a72f4 -[NSObject(NSObject)     doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 220
3   CoreFoundation                  0x1846a40a8 ___forwarding___ + 928
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1845a696c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
5   UIKit                           0x189156814 -[UIGestureRecognizer     _delegateShouldReceiveTouch:] + 152
6   UIKit                           0x1891565f4 -[UITouchesEvent     _addGestureRecognizersForView:toTouch:currentTouchMap:newTouchMap:] + 912
7   UIKit                           0x18914977c -[UITouchesEvent     _addTouch:forDelayedDelivery:] + 624
8   UIKit                           0x1891494c0 _AddTouchToEvent + 196
9   UIKit                           0x1893bdc80     _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 14236
10  UIKit                           0x18911b488     _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1716
11  CoreFoundation                  0x184657f8c     __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
```

Answer (score 0):

in ios8 set

```
allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = YES;
```

then set

```
allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = NO;
```

The app will crash when you touched WKWebView